# Ubuntu mini ベースシステムのインストールでエラーになる原因が知りたい

Tags: ubuntu

提示画像ですがベースシステムのインストールエラーが出ます。これはどうすればいいのでしょうか？調べましたがわかりません。そもそもコマンドラインを触ることができないため調べたサイトに書いてある `sudo` や `apt-get install` などのコマンドは実行できません、設定のシェルが使えましたがコマンドが打てません。どうすればいいのでしょうか？

仮想環境
OS: Windows10 64bit
Vmware Player
メモリ１GB
プロセッサ２
ストレージ１GB

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

仮想マシンに割り当てたディスク容量が 1GB で少なすぎるのが原因じゃないでしょうか。
最低でも 8～10GB 程度は必要かと思います。(推奨は恐らく 25GB 程度)

**参考:** (インストール要件)
[What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795)
[Installation/SystemRequirements - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

また、インストール中にコマンドを実行する必要がある場合には、画面に表示されている通り「仮想コンソール」を切り替えます。
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> の組み合わせでファンクションキー　(F1～F12)　を押せばいいのですが、
「仮想コンソール 4」は <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> になります。

ただし仮想環境 (VMware) の場合には、以下の手順で切り替える必要があるようです。

[Linux 仮想マシンでのテキスト コンソールの切り替え (1006012)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1006012?lang=ja)

> CTRL + ALT の組み合わせは、キーボード入力をホストに送るために VMware が使用します。
> CTRL + ALT + Space を押し、CTRL + ALT を押しながら F1 キー（または適切なファンクション キー）を押します。

Comment: 質問ですがコマンドラインでもそんなにたくさんの容量が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: デスクトップ環境を入れない "Server" としてのインストールでも、2.5GB 程度は必要と出てきます。 / 保存用のストレージは大容量が安価に手に入る時代なので、極端にケチっても意味がないと思います。

Comment: 自分はCUIのubuntu環境が欲しいのでインストールしました。3GBにストレージを設定したところ上手く行きました。