# Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTSのインストールができない

Tags: ubuntu

VirtualBox上に、Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTSをインストールしていますが、
インストール完了の直前に、添付ファイルのメッセージがでてしまい、インストールが出来な状況です。

ISOファイルは、下記からDLしております。
https://jp.ubuntu.com/download

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [VirtualBox を使用して仮想マシンで Ubuntu デスクトップを実行する方法](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox) のステップに従うとよいはず。違うところ無いですか？ あるいは再度手順に従い試すとか

Comment: [こちらの方](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436198)は、インストールディスク容量が小さすぎたためそのようなエラーが起こっていたようです。(また、リンク先には `/var/log/syslog` 参照手順についても言及があります)

Comment: オススメはしませんが、wget 'https://linux.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-signed/linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58_amd64.deb' でパッケージ取ってきて、dpkg -e linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58_amd64.deb で展開し、
view DEBIAN/postinst で何をするはずなのか見ることができますよ。

Comment: 重複候補: [Ubuntu mini ベースシステムのインストールでエラーになる原因が知りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/72881) / 仮想マシンの HDD に割り当てているディスク容量を確認してみてください。